# Problems using the navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to use the navigation stack, but I have some problems.

Well, I've configured the parameters as [the tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) says. Then I use Rviz for setting the estimated position and the goal. Doing that, I can make the robot move, but I get this warning messages in the console:

```
[ WARN] [1350459884.039970066, 6963.543000000]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1350459887.093712554, 6968.750000000]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 6968.7500, global_pose stamp: 6968.4210, tolerance: 0.3000
```

I don't know if it's normal to recieve this warnings (I suppose it's not). I think that the reason why I recieve this warnings is because the frequency of my laser scan is only 2 Hz, but I'm not sure.

In addition, the robot is not able to avoid obstacles, and that tells me that I'm missing something.

For more detail, here's my costmap parameters:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /odom
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.2 #0.05

global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
```

Can anyone give me a clue? Thanks in advance ;-)

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte.

EDITED: More info.
I've set the frequency of the laser to the max (8Hz) and the warning continues.

With `rosrun tf tf_monitor` I get:

```
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: /back_left_wheel published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.000126582 Max Delay: 0.006
Frame: /back_right_wheel published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.000126582 Max Delay: 0.006
Frame: /base_footprint published by /summit_xl_odometry Average Delay: -0.00904412 Max Delay: 0.001
Frame: /base_link published by /summit_xl_tf_node Average Delay: -0.256207 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /front_left_wheel published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.000126582 Max Delay: 0.006
Frame: /front_right_wheel published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.000126582 Max Delay: 0.006
Frame: /imu_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.509563 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /odom published by /amcl Average Delay: 0.0235 Max Delay: 0.081
Frame: /openni_depth_frame published by /summit_xl_tf_node Average Delay: -0.00770476 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /tof_link published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.509563 Max Delay: 0

All Broadcasters:
Node: /amcl 8.27301 Hz, Average Delay: 0.0235 Max Delay: 0.081
Node: /robot_state_publisher 88.6508 Hz, Average Delay: -0.288324 Max Delay: 0.006
Node: /summit_xl_odometry 98.4556 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00904412 Max Delay: 0.001
Node: /summit_xl_tf_node 101.597 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00769048 Max Delay: 0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46056/problems-using-the-navigation-stack/) by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-10-16**:
How do you get robot state vector? I had similar problem with navigation, when published odometry too slow. From my experience suffficient rate is round 50 Hz. My laser update rate is 20 Hz.

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-10-16**:
I have a simulated odometry, that publish the robot information at 100 Hz. I think that the model I use is based on a gazebo plugin, but I'm not sure. But the navigation only uses the laser scan and estimates its position with an AMCL. Thats the reason why I think the problem is the laser frequency

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-10-16**:
can you show the results of 'rosrun tf tf_monitor'

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-10-17**:
Added to the question ;)

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-10-17**:
increase the tolarence rate, you may decrease the map size

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-10-17**:
The map size is not so big, is 400 x 400 with 0.2m/pixel. And I don't know how to increase the tolerance rate, I dont' know where is this parameter

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-10-17**:
Ok, I've found a yaml for a roomba and there's a lot of parameters that I didn't set. Now with all the parameters configured I don't have the warnings and all works better. Tanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are good places to look when there are navigation problems:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi weiin, this is a comment / answer, so I'll answer you here ;)

Well, I followed those tutorials and only with that I didn't achieve anything. Probably the problem is that I'm new in ROS and I need to learn more.

My main problem was that there were lot of parameters that I wasn't tuning. This links helped me with that:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner

http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d

http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base

---

Originally posted by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) with karma: 229 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-01-22**:
I have exactly similar problem, can you please tell where (in terms of files) exactly you have set the parameters. @g.aterido

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2014-02-02**:
Hi, Brian. I'm sorry, but that was a project I was doing long time ago and I don't have those files anymore :( I don't remember exactly how but I solved it by setting the parameters detailed in the links above. In addition you must be careful with the name of the params (run rosparam list to know ...

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2014-02-02**:
... the real name of the params, because the names mentioned in the links may be different from the real ones).